# user without camera can't accept video from another user

Tags: html5-video, webrtc

When user A without camera call to user B with camera, hi will receive stream without video
tracks. In this case user B generate SDP with such string `a=group:BUNDLE audio` when normally it contain mentions about video like `a=group:BUNDLE audio video` and `m=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96`

Here is my code in coffeescript for accepting offer:

```
acccept_offer: (sdp, success) ->
  sdp = new _RTCSessionDescription sdp

  @connection.setRemoteDescription sdp, =>
    if @candidates.length
      for candidate in @candidates
        @connection.addIceCandidate candidate
      @candidates = []
    @connection.createAnswer (description) =>
      description = new _RTCSessionDescription
        sdp: @set_bandwidth description.sdp
        type: description.type
      @local_description = description
      @connection.setLocalDescription @local_description, ->
        success()
      , (e) ->
        console.log e
    , (e) ->
      console.log e
  , (e) ->
    console.log e
```

Why this strange behaviour and how can I avoid it?

Comment: What are the peerconnection constraints. You should be able to set if you are receive only/send only for each media type. Ex: `var sdpConstraints = { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': false } };`

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, I put constraints in createOffer/createAnswer and now it work like a charm. Thanx for advice. Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put constraints in your RTCPeerConnection creation to tell the SDP what media you are willing to send/receive.

Example:

```
var sdpConstraints = { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': false } };
```